# How to easily convert and breakdown a text curve object into separated character objects?

Tags: python, scripting, bezier-curves, conversion

How do i easily convert a text curve object into separated character objects?

[image: separate chars]

The characters should stay in place but the origin should be changed to a more convenient location, like a combination of `top/middle/bottom` and `left, center, right`

[image]

Even using python scripting this is quite difficult because after converting the information about the relations between the characters and their splines seem to be lost.

I.e. the character `i` consists of two parts and the characters `a, e` are defined by two splines.

Comment: I'm not sure it's clear what you are asking for. Do you just want each letter to be a separate curve object with individual origins?

Comment: Select all, press P and select By Loose Parts?

Comment: @Denis in case of `i` it will separate the dot from the letter

Comment: Good point, but it's still your best option. You can join the `i` base and the dot back after separating it. Otherwise, you would need to let a script create every letter individually, but positioning them correct will be tough (requires font kerning information - unless you are fine with a brute-force approach, i.e. identical spacing between every letter).